# Time lapse didn’t save, possible to recover?

Tags: iphone, camera

I recorded a six hour long timelapse and upon stopping the recording it simply didn’t show up in my camera roll. On googling this it appears to be a very common problem.

Is there any way the file may have become corrupted and can be recovered if so?